# XYTextAnnotation in DynamicTimeSeriesCollection

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to implement XYTextAnnotation in DynamicTimeSeriesCollection. 
I have no idea how to find X value of series in DynamicTimeSeriesCollection. My code so far:

```
DynamicTimeSeriesCollection dataset = new DynamicTimeSeriesCollection(1, 60, new Minute());
final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(TITLE, "A", "B", dataset, true, true, false);
float[] series1Small = new float[10];
dataset.setTimeBase(new Minute(1, 1, 1, 1, 2013));
dataset.addSeries(series1Small,0,"1");
JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(TITLE, "Время", "Платежи", dataset, true, true, false);
final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
-----------------------------------------------------------Below line doesn't work. 

TimeSeriesDataItem item1 = series1.getDataItem(series1.getItemCount() - 1);
createAnnotation(item1,plot);
```

This is a function that used to work for annotation with TimeSeriesCollection.

```
 public static void createAnnotation(TimeSeriesDataItem item,XYPlot plot)
{
   double xAnnotation = item.getPeriod().getFirstMillisecond();
   double yAnnotation = item.getValue().doubleValue();
   XYTextAnnotation annotation = new XYTextAnnotation(item.getValue().toString(), xAnnotation, yAnnotation);
   annotation.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,11));
   plot.addAnnotation(annotation);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't it work exactly? Where is `series1` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting form this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513), I added the following lines in `createChart()` to obtain the image below:

```
double x = dataset.getXValue(0, COUNT - 1);
double y = dataset.getYValue(0, COUNT - 1);
String s = dataset.getY(0, COUNT - 1).toString();
XYTextAnnotation a = new XYTextAnnotation(s, x, y);
a.setFont(a.getFont().deriveFont(24f));
plot.addAnnotation(a);
```

[image: text annotation image]